# Explanation of UMAP assumptions

Tags: assumptions, manifold-learning, umap

Uniform Manifold Approximation (UMAP) is a technique for dimensionality reduction  and visualization. The author of [UMAP](https://umap-learn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) states that the algorithm is founded on three assumptions about the data:

> 1. The data is uniformly distributed on Riemannian manifold;
> 2. The Riemannian metric is locally constant (or can be approximated as such);
> 3. The manifold is locally connected.

Can someone give an accessible explanation of these assumptions? (Let's say accessible to a bioinformatician/statistics enthusiast). Also, when are these assumptions *not* satisfied?

The "layman" material I found explains how UMAP works without discussing these assumptions. This makes me think that these assumptions are almost always satisfied - still, I'd be curious to know what they mean.

---

26/10/2022 Edit: Crossposted on [UMAP repository](https://github.com/lmcinnes/umap/issues/935) since nobody replied yet.